# Getting stacks and legends in order

Tags: python, python-3.5, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh to generate some graphs, trying to visualize a survey feedback. I'm using the stacked Bar high-level object, and I have two issues.

1. I cannot get the legend to sort; and
2. I can't find out how to get the stacks to be in the same order. The stacks should preferably correspond to the chapter order of the survey for all columns.

What I write is a POC only, so the code contains its own test data. I have tried:

1. using `legend_sort_direction = 'ascending'`, but it just doesn't sort the legends (is this a bug bug?)
2. I've sifted through the 'net for data, I find some answers on how to create the graphs from scratch... Well, yes, but getting the Bar functionality to work would be really nice.

Code:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from random import randrange
import random
from collections import OrderedDict
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer
from bokeh.charts.attributes import CatAttr
from bokeh.models import Range1d
import calendar

ChapterName = ['05: Information security policies',
               '06: Organization of information security',
               '07: Human resource security',
               '08: Asset management',
               '09: Access control',
               '10: Cryptography',
               '11: Physical and environmental security',
               '12: Operations security',
               '13: Communications security',
               '14: System acquisition, development and maintenance',
               '15: Supplier relationships',
               '16: Information security incident management',
               '17: Information security aspects of business continuity management',
               '18: Compliance']

# Do some random stuff here
UserName = ['Vanita.Marton',
            'Tula.Falls',
            'Simonne.Linzy',
            'Donald.Eggebrecht',
            'Deadra.Jahn',
            'Leah.Conrad',
            'Susie.Dolin',
            'Gretta.Brumbelow',
            'Dong.Mowrey',
            'Georgetta.Delk',
            'Princess.Mccook',
            'Joe.Edgley',
            'Lonnie.Oppenheimer',
            'Ethel.Presler',
            'Lura.Byerley',
            'Maile.Mccaskey',
            'Charissa.Degroat',
            'Deloras.Deskin',
            'Travis.Phillis',
            'Rachelle.Bane']

# do some random stuff here
Brands = ['AB Flug',
          'AC',
          'Acura',
          'Aerogear',
          'APR Performance',
          'Aston Martin',
          'Audi',
          'Bentley',
          'BMW',
          'Border',
          'Buick',
          'Cadillac',
          'Chevrolet',
          'Chrysler',
          'Datsun',
          'Dodge',
          'Eagle',
          'Ferrari',
          'Ford',
          'Guldstrand',
          'Hennessey',
          'Honda',
          'Hyundai',
          'Infiniti',
          'INGS',
          'Jaguar',
          'Koenigsegg',
          'Lancia',
          'Lexus',
          'Lingenfelter',
          'Lotus',
          'Mazda',
          'McLaren',
          'Mercedes',
          'Mine',
          'MINI',
          'Mitsubishi',
          'Mugen',
          'Nissan',
          'Opel',
          'Pagani',
          'Panoz',
          'Peugeot',
          'Pontiac',
          'Porsche',
          'Renault',
          'Saab',
          'Saleen',
          'Seat',
          'Shelby',
          'Sparco',
          'Subaru',
          'Tommy Kaira',
          'Tom',
          'Toyota',
          'TVR',
          'Vauxhall',
          'Veilside',
          'VIS Racing',
          'Volkswagen',
          'Volvo',
          'Wings West']

Comment = ['Just a comment','Another comment']

Answers = ['G','R','P','B']

g_data = r_data = p_data = b_data = data = {
    'UserName': [],
    'DeclName' : [],
    'Quid' : [],
    'ChapterName' : [],
    'AnswerCodes' : [],
    'Comment' : [],
    }

for i in range(1, 10000):
    currentUserName = random.choice(UserName)
    currentDeclName = random.choice(Brands) # Let car names be declaration names
    currentQuid = randrange(1,100)
    currentAnswer = random.choice(Answers)
    currentChapterName = random.choice(ChapterName)
    currentComment = random.choice(Comment)

    # Data structure with all answers
    data['UserName'].append(currentUserName)
    data['DeclName'].append(currentDeclName)
    data['Quid'].append(currentQuid)
    data['ChapterName'].append(currentChapterName)
    data['AnswerCodes'].append(currentAnswer)
    data['Comment'].append(currentComment)

    if(currentAnswer =='G'): # Reduced data structure with the G answers
        g_data['UserName'].append(currentUserName)
        g_data['DeclName'].append(currentDeclName)
        g_data['Quid'].append(currentQuid)
        g_data['ChapterName'].append(currentChapterName)        
        g_data['AnswerCodes'].append(currentAnswer)
        g_data['Comment'].append(currentComment)


bar = Bar(data, values='AnswerCodes', label=CatAttr(columns=['UserName'], sort=True), agg='count', legend_sort_direction = 'ascending', stack='AnswerCodes', title="Answer Codes per user", plot_width=900, legend='top_right', tools='pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,save,undo, redo, reset')
g_bar = Bar(g_data, values='AnswerCodes', label='UserName', agg='count', legend_sort_direction = 'ascending', stack=CatAttr(columns=['ChapterName'], sort=True), title="Compliant per chapter", plot_width=900, legend='top_right', tools='hover')

glyph_renderers = bar.select(dict(type=GlyphRenderer))
bar_source = glyph_renderers[0].data_source

hover = bar.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [
    ('Answer code', '@AnswerCodes'),
    ('User', '@UserName')
    ]

hover = g_bar.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [
    ('Chapter', '@ChapterName'),
    ('User', '@UserName')
    ]

show(column(bar, g_bar))
```

Comment: not sure I'm getting everything. You mean that the dictionaries are not sorted the way you populate them? if that's it, at least for this problem you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Jean-Francois, but that was not my problem. I can have the dictionaries sorted but it did not change the way the stuff appears in the graph. I can not upload pictures yet (being a newbie :-) but if you run the code you will see...